# Getting only the email addresses domain name from an array of email addresses

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

I have searched all day on stack overflow and google and can't find the exact thing I need. I have an array of email addresses i will get from the user. `Ex. [asdfgg@gmail.com, fgtrreds@yahoo.com, dgfit@gmail.com]`. I am wanting to split all of the email addresses and then push just the `[@gmail.com, @yahoo.com]`, etc. to a new array.

> **Here is a JavaScript function I have been messing with all day**

```
function EmailFunction() {
var emailNames = [];
var emailDomains = [];

emailNames = $("#emailing").val();

var len = emailNames.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

   var domain = emailNames.split("@").pop();
    emailDomains.push(domain);
}
console.log("Email Domains = " + domain);

console.log("Function Names = " + emailNames);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You were missing to add `[i]` before the `emailNames` just do it like the following

```js
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

function EmailFunction() {
  var emailNames = [];
  var emailDomains = [];
  emailNames = ['asdfgg@gmail.com', 'fgtrreds@yahoo.com', 'dgfit@gmail.com']
  var len = emailNames.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var domain = emailNames[i].split("@").pop();
    emailDomains.push(domain)
    var unique = emailDomains.filter(onlyUnique);
  }
  console.log(unique)
}
EmailFunction()
```

Comment: The OP has in the question unique elements with the @.

Comment: @Gad thats so weird as its working on here but its not working when i put this code in. I am getting a array of 18 indexes back. its putting a comma between each letter. I will add  an image to my orginal post.

Comment: check if you're copying all code correctly in mine the code is working

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with just one line

```js
const emailNames = ['asdfgg@gmail.com', 'fgtrreds@yahoo.com', 'dgfit@gmail.com'];
const result = Object.keys(emailNames.map(e => e.split("@")[1]).reduce((o, e) => ({ ...o, [e]: null }), {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's a little bit to easy: The OP has in the question unique elements with the @

Answer (score 0):

I give only unique domains as result. For this I iterate with foreach, get the domain (inclusive @) with substr and indexof, look if it's in the resultarray. If not push it there.

```js
function getDomains(mailings) {
    let result = [];
    mailings.forEach(mail => {
        let domain = mail.substr(mail.indexOf('@'));
        if  (result.indexOf(domain) == -1)
            result.push(domain);
    });
    return result;
}

let mailings = ['asdfgg@gmail.com', 'fgtrreds@yahoo.com', 'dgfit@gmail.com'];
console.log(getDomains(mailings));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want duplicates in the final list, you can do it like this

```
const emailNames = ['asdfgg@gmail.com', 'fgtrreds@yahoo.com', 'dgfit@gmail.com'];
car emailDomains = [];

for(let i=0; i < emailNames.length; i++) {
    let domain = emailNames[i].split("@")[1];
    if(emailDomains.imdexOf(domain) == -1) {
        emailDomains.push(domain);
    }
}
console.log(emailDomains);
```